# How to get the disassembly line without offset translations in IDAPython?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, idapython

When I use `GetDisasm()`to get disassembly line, I find out that it will show some memory references as a variable name.

For example, when raw assembly is:

```
mov %r15, 0x20b062(%rip)`
```

`GetDisasm()`'s output may be:

```
mov r15d, offset s1
```

I was hoping there is a way to get the raw instruction, rather than the modified one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, IDA's disassembly cannot be separated from it's data type information that is inherent to IDA (and is considered one of it's biggest advantages).

You could, however, alter that information manually to get IDA to display the disassembly as you please. For example, you could use the `idc.OpHex(ea, n)` API function to make an instruction operand to hexadecimal number format.

For example, in order to change the type of the second operand from offset parameter type to hexadecimal parameter type, you can call `idc.OpHex` with the address of the instruction as the first parameter and the operand number as the second parameter (`1` in your example), or `-1` for all operands.

For example, given the following instruction in IDA:

```
.text:00401421                 mov     ebx, offset aL4jDontWait ; "--l4j-dont-wait"
```

and the output:

```
Python>idc.GetDisasm(0x0401421)
mov     ebx, offset aL4jDontWait; "--l4j-dont-wait"
Python>idc.OpHex(0x0401421, 1)
True
Python>idc.GetDisasm(0x0401421)
mov     ebx, 407000h
```

You could then just load a previous save to "undo" all of those changes.

Comment: Why not just call GetOperandValue() and replace into the string instead of changing the type in the IDB?

Comment: That's also possible, but seems more error prone IMHO